# Pylint warning: Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence

Tags: python, tuples, pylint, packing

I have a piece of Python code:

```
def func1():                                                                                                                  
    a=set()
    b = ','.join(map(str, list(a)))
    return  b, []

def func2():
    d = 1
    e = 2
    return func1() + (d, e,)

def main():
    a,b,c,d = func2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it through `pylint` (1.4.0), I receive the warning:

```
W: 12, 4: Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence: left side has 4 label(s), right side has 3 value(s) (unbalanced-tuple-unpacking)
```

It seems that `func2` will always return four results. What does the error mean and why?

Comment: It says *possible* (and `W` is just a **w**arning). Evidently the introspection isn't deep enough to determine that `func1` always returns a two-tuple, and therefore that `func2` always returns a four-tuple. Given that you know it isn't a problem, you could add `# pylint: disable=unbalanced-tuple-unpacking` to the offending line.

Answer (score 21):

If the warning is erroneous, it can be disabled by appending `# pylint: disable=unbalanced-tuple-unpacking` to the line.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of pylint (3.0.2 as of 2023-11-23) does not have this bug any more:

```
$ pylint test_pylint_unpacking.py
************* Module test_pylint_unpacking
test_pylint_unpacking.py:1:12: C0303: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:1:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:6:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:11:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:12:4: W0612: Unused variable 'a' (unused-variable)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:12:6: W0612: Unused variable 'b' (unused-variable)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:12:8: W0612: Unused variable 'c' (unused-variable)
test_pylint_unpacking.py:12:10: W0612: Unused variable 'd' (unused-variable)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 2.50/10
```