# Avoiding unbalanced-tuple-unpacking warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

When you run pylint on code like this

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def func1(string):
    split = []

    for sub in string.split(" "):
        split.append(sub)

    return split

def main(string):
    a, b, c, d = func1(string)
    print(a, b, c, d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    input1 = "some random words !"
    # note that the string will always contain exactly three spaces
    assert input1.count(" ") == 3

    main(input1)
```

you receive the message:

```sh
Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence defined at line 4: left side has 4 label(s), right side has 0 value(s) 
(unbalanced-tuple-unpacking)
```

As the warning states, a unbalanced tuple unpacking is **possible** here. In this case, it won't happen in reality due to the assertion. Different other solutions state that one could disable this exact warning via the configuration (s. [Pylint warning: Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980121/pylint-warning-possible-unbalanced-tuple-unpacking-with-sequence)) to solve this. However, I would rather avoid disabling it since the warning might be useful at another point in the code. Hence, I tried a few things and one solution that avoids this message is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def func1(string):
    split = []

    for sub in string.split(" "):
        split.append(sub)

    return split

def main(string):
    # note the * operator
    a, b, c, d, *_ = func1(string)
    print(a, b, c, d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    input1 = "some random words !"
    # note that the string will always contain exactly three spaces
    assert input1.count(" ") == 3

    main(input1)
```

However, this appears like a rather ugly workaround to me. Do you agree? If so do you have other solutions to avoid the warning?

Comment: If you only ever want 3 splits, `split = string.split(" ", 3)` (and maybe `assert len(split) == 4` afterward, if that helps to clue Pylint in...).

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried this and it does not work. Even putting ``assert len(split) == 4`` directly after the for loop does not help. Also ``func1`` might be called from other places where different numbers of splits are required.

Comment: It's really hard for linters to detect dynamic constraints like this.

Answer (score 1):

PyLint is unhappy because you are dynamically appending to a list, as opposed to creating a one-off list. To fix this, you can create a one-off list by using either a comprehension or the list type.

To fix your example:

```py
def func1(string):
    split = list(string.split(" "))
    return split


def main(string):
    a, b, c, d = func1(string)
    print(a, b, c, d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input1 = "some random words !"
    # note that the string will always contain exactly three spaces
    assert input1.count(" ") == 3

    main(input1)
```